# Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain], main() threw exception, Output directory not set in JobConf

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to execute mapreduce job in hue. I got the following error:

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain], main() threw exception, Output directory not set in JobConf.
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set in JobConf.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:1015)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:974)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:974)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:948)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.submitJob(MapReduceMain.java:97)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.run(MapReduceMain.java:57)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.main(MapReduceMain.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:495)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher ends
```

Can somebody please tell what can be done to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not set `mapred.output.dir` property in your oozie workflow. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi DMA, Thank you. But i have already added that property. Is there anything i need to add like path or something?

Comment: I don't think so. The error clearly says `Output directory not set in JobConf`. Can you post your workflow.xml here?